# Failed to fetch http://in.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80

Tags: apt, updates

**I have installed ubuntu (20.04) on MacBookpro using UTM virtual machine. I have added architecture i386 while installing wine using below command.
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 and sudo apt update**

I am getting below error while update command. I don't know how to solve this.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

---

```
Ign:19 http://in.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
E: Failed to fetch http://in.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have found that you can't get i386 on some architectures (I believe). I am trying to figure out how to get it but so far have had no luck. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: well according to this article, it is not possible without emulation, which is ridiculously slow on UTM. If you really need i386, you are going to have trouble doing anything with it using UTM, unfortunately: https://nomadic-dmitry.medium.com/apple-silicon-m1-how-to-run-x86-and-arm-virtual-machines-on-it-cdd9d9054483

Answer (score 2):

There is no `binary-i386` subdirectory on that server which is why you can't connect to it.

Suggest examining whatever procedure told you to attempt this.

[image]